# Unicode character in propertyname

Tags: javascript, typescript, unicode

I need a response from a public API that contains the letter ø (\u00f8).
I'm using angular, and I use an interface to make my responses typed.

```
export interface Response{
  øl: string; // instead of ø I would like to use \u00f8 (or something similiar)  
}
```

The problem is I have some international coworkers that do not have ø in their alphabet. Creating strings with Unicode is easy, but how can I do it with property names?

Comment: Can you please give a better description of when your coworkers would have problems with øl apart from typing it? When would they need to type these characters? Tell them you will buy them an øl if they add a keyboard layout

Comment: Alternatively ask them to type alt-0248

Comment: I think the solution to the problem will be the same even if I gave a more detailed description of why it is a problem for them.  I have +1000 coworkers, so I can't afford to buy so many beers :)

Comment: What I mean is, WHY is it important that they can type the key if it is a response

Comment: so they don't have to type the letter ø?
for example: this.beerService.getAll().subscribe(b => this.goodBeers =  b.øl !== 'Heineken' );

Comment: So the usecase is they need to type...

Comment: But would it be possible to remove the ø in our code base to be more specific :) ?

Comment: See my updated answer. JS does not care

Comment: Okay. I can see that the " " also works in interfaces.  Thanks a lot! :). If we ever meet I'll give you a beer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "Yes they can use unicode entities instead of the characters they cannot type"

In your case they could use \u00F8 for `ø`

```js
const response = {
"øl":"",
"b\u00C6":"",
"": "b\u00E6",
"f\u00F8l": ""
}
console.log(response["\u00F8l"])
console.log(response["øl"])
console.log(response[""])
console.log(response["føl"])

console.log(Object.entries(response)
  .filter(([key,value]) => key.includes("\u00F8")))
  
  console.log(Object.entries(response)
  .filter(([key,value]) => key.includes("ø")))
```